# Copy & paste in MS Word (XAML)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Why I can't paste this XAML in MS Word?

I've made two tests. This is the first:

```
string xaml = "<Window x:Class=\"WpfApplication2.MainWindow\"" +
              "xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\""+
              "xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\"" + 
              "Title=\"MainWindow\" Height=\"350\" Width=\"525\">" +
              "<Grid>" +
              "<Path Data=\"M119.33333,85 L317.50034,159.83333\" Fill=\"#FFF4F4F5\" HorizontalAlignment=\"Left\" Height=\"75.833\" Margin=\"119.333,85,0,0\" Stretch=\"Fill\" Stroke=\"Black\" VerticalAlignment=\"Top\" Width=\"199.167\"/>" +
              "<Rectangle Fill=\"#FFF4F4F5\" HorizontalAlignment=\"Left\" Height=\"95.333\" Margin=\"100.667,145.667,0,0\" Stroke=\"Black\" VerticalAlignment=\"Top\" Width=\"106\"/>" +
              "</Grid>" +
              "</Window>";

DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.Xaml, xaml);

Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);
```

and this is the second:

```
string xaml = "<Path Stroke=\"Black\" StrokeThickness=\"1\" Fill=\"#CCCCFF\">" +
              "<Path.Data>" +
              "<GeometryGroup>" +
              "<RectangleGeometry Rect=\"50,5 100,10\" />" +
              "<RectangleGeometry Rect=\"5,5 95,180\" />" +
              "<EllipseGeometry Center=\"100, 100\" RadiusX=\"20\" RadiusY=\"30\"/>"+
              "<RectangleGeometry Rect=\"50,175 100,10\" />"+
               "<PathGeometry>"+
                 "<PathGeometry.Figures>"+
                   "<PathFigureCollection>" +
                     "<PathFigure IsClosed=\"true\" StartPoint=\"50,50\">"+
                       "<PathFigure.Segments>"+
                         "<PathSegmentCollection>"+
                           "<BezierSegment Point1=\"75,300\" Point2=\"125,100\" Point3=\"150,50\"/>"+
                           "<BezierSegment Point1=\"125,300\" Point2=\"75,100\"  Point3=\"50,50\"/>"+
                          "</PathSegmentCollection>"+
                         "</PathFigure.Segments>"+
                        "</PathFigure>"+
                       "</PathFigureCollection>"+
                      "</PathGeometry.Figures>"+
                     "</PathGeometry>"+
                    "</GeometryGroup>"+
                   "</Path.Data>"+
                  "</Path>";

DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.Xaml, xaml);

Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);
```

Comment: Are you pasting it, while the application (with above code) is still running?

Comment: What do you want to see in Word? The verbatim text? some magic?

Comment: @DrKotch: The vector drawing, of course.

Comment: @Alberto I asked, because as per the documentation, the `SetDataObject` overload you are using, the app must stay running for the data to be available on clipboard.. So if the app is running, that shouldn't be the problem.